# Can I not use django.contrib.contenttypes?

Tags: django

I'm using django 3.0.

I use `django-admin startproject mysite` and created a sample django project.

I don't think the sample project has any models so I commented out `"django.contrib.contenttypes"` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py. I also commented out all middlewares.

I then wrote a simple view

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'hello.html')
```

and hello.html is just a blank file.

Once I access the page, django throws exception

> Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't
>   declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in
>   INSTALLED_APPS.

Can anyone help explain the exception? The sample project doesn't have any model, why do I need `django.contrib.contenttypes`? Can django websites live without `django.contrib.contenttypes`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have to remove `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` in TEMPLATES.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+"/templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                # 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                # 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Did not answer the question